# While loop for an index existing

Tags: c#, while-loop, indexof

How could I write a while loop that said the following (pseudo code):

```
While the index of "blahblah" in string 1 exists

do this
```

Comment: Your psuedocode is almost real C#. Why not learn how to write this in C# yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(string1.Contains("blahblah")) {
    // do this
}
```

Pseudocode compiled to C# successfully. 0 errors, 0 warnings. Time taken: 0:00:01.860.

Comment: funny, that's quite similar to `if(string1.Contains("blahblah")) while(true){ DoThis();}` and loops forever...

Comment: @agent-j: Not if `string1` is modified from `DoThis()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var string1 = "blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah ";
  int pos = -1;
  while (0 >= (pos = string1.IndexOf("blahblah", pos + 1)))
  {
     // do this.
  }
```

Comment: Note that this always executes at least once, even if string1 doesn't contain any blahblahs. Also, I think you're making assumptions about what OP wants that I don't really get from the question. This looks more like "execute once for each blahblah in string1". Maybe that's right though.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Oops.. I introduced a bug trying to make previous code more elegant.  Thanks... Fixed.